# Error on running a Cordova app with Crosswalk on Android 4.0

Tags: android, cordova, web-audio-api, crosswalk

I am building a hybrid mobile app with Cordova, and my app uses Web Audio.

On iOS, the WebView supports Web Audio, but on Android, only 6.0+'s WebView supports it. I am trying to use Crosswalk, so my WebView is actually a Chromium WebView supporting the Web Audio.

Unfortunately, Crosswalk's Chromium WebView seem to disable support for Web Audio on Android 4.0. Building for 4.4, works in a x86 emulator. But on Android 4.0 AudioContext isn't defined. And checking the userAgent, I clearly see it's Crosswalk's webView, not the default one.